# Reversing number created based on string

Tags: c, encryption, reverse-engineering

Is possible to make the reverse process of this algorithm?

```
int EDI = 0x1505;
for( int i = 0; i < lstrlen(dir); i++ )
{
  if ( dir[i] != '.' && dir[i] != '\' )
  {
     EDX = EDI * 32;
     EDX = EDX + EDI;
     EDX = EDX + dir[i];
     EDI = EDX;
  }
}
```

The `dir` is a string, for example, when `dir` is "data\etcobject\damagecri.nif" the output of that function would be: `1C9EA36C`.

Is there a way to retrieve the original string giving only the output number?

Comment: Is `dir` a `struct` or something else? C is not C++ and does not have `std::string` objects.

Comment: I have edited the code.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot reverse this function because it is lossy; it has fewer output bits than input bits, so inevitably multiple inputs will return the same output. For example, it ignores `.` and `/`, so the inputs `ab`, `a/b`, and `a.b` will be the same.

Even if you ignore `.` and `/` there is no way; you are converting a string to an integer; there are waaaaaay more strings than integers, so inevitably multiple strings will result in the same integer.

Comment: Even if I lose the `.` and `/ ` characters.. is there a way ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to retrieve the original string giving only the output number?

In general: No.

---

Note that

```
EDX = EDI * 32;
EDX = EDX + EDI;
// same as 
EDX = EDI *33'
```

Consider the 2 strings `A` and `B` with length 2.

```
The `EDI` generated are
EDI(A) = 33*A[0] + A[1] + constant
EDI(B) = 33*B[0] + B[1] + constant

with `A[0] == 2, A[1] ==  3` we get `33*2 +  3 + constant` or `69 + constant`
with `B[0] == 1, B[1] == 36` we get `33*1 + 36 + constant` or `69 + constant`
```

So with an `EDI` of `69 + constant` we can not distinguish between the 2 string originals (or many other candidates).

---

Another way to look at it is we assume only `A-Z` was used: then with 7 or more alpha characters, there are more than `pow(26,7) or 8,031,810,176` combinations and an `int` (assume 32-bit) has at best `4,294,967,296` combinations.  So there is no way to distinguish all 7 long strings with as 32-bit `int`.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 EDX = EDI * 32;
 EDX = EDX + EDI;
 EDX = EDX + dir[i];
 EDI = EDX;
```

is obviously identical to:

```
 EDX = EDX * 33 + dir[i];
```

So it would be only possible to reverse strings when dir[i] would be inside a range of 33 (e.g. 0-32 or 97 - 129) and EDX does not overflow.

So, if you could assume that the string only has minuscles (which are ascii 97-122, it might be possible:

- First, subtract 0x1505 from `VAL`
- Then, calculate `ch = VAL % 33`
- Calculate `ch = ch + n*33`. Choose n in a way to get `ch` into the range 97-129, this is the next char.
- Subtract this char from `VAL` and divide by 33: `VAL = (VAL - ch) / 33`
- Iterate from step 2 until VAL is 0.

This can be further improved by bringing `ch` into other ranges of the ascii range (e.g. numbers, uppercase letters) if you feel, that the calculated char is incorrect. But this makes the algorithm heuristic then.

Another method: If you have a list of candidate strings (or you can generate one), then you could feed your algorithm with it and compare it to the number.

Comment: Can you elaborate more the steps you described? I can't understand why you are doing `ch = VAL % 33` and after `ch = n * 33`. `N` is the variable used in the for loop, right?

Comment: No, n is a natural number chosen in a way to get ch from 0-32 to the target range, i.e. 97-129 if you are looking for lowercase letters. So, if VAL % 33 results in 10, choose n = 3 to boost it to 10+3*33=109.

Comment: Why choose n = 3 ? I don't understand the logic you are using. Why not 4, or 5 ?

Comment: because 10+4*33=142, which is outside our expected scope of 97-129. Remember, we assume that dir[i] is always a lowercase-letter, which are all included in the range 97-129

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/VSWRv4iA The string that should be returned is `data\map\realworld_r\01_yokohama\105\map_data\105.emr` but it is returning `fkvdmjztxj`